# PHP-LDAP How can I use ldap_add() with userPassword and UserAccountControl

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm using PHP 5.6.31
I have to create LDAP accounts with HTTPS web interface.

I have a problem with two ldap fields:

1. UserAccountControl : I have to set 66048 value (544 value works correctly) but i have this error: Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform in C:****\traitement.php on line 82
2. userPassword : The password in my Active Directory seems don't match with the password set on the web interface but no PHP error returned.

[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFUv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on a [secured connection to modify a password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx) (and probably other security related options).

Add the following before you call `ldap_bind()`:

```
ldap_start_tls($ds);
```

This is a good idea even if you aren't trying to change a password as otherwise your bind operation is cleartext and can be sniffed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think it can works with tls.
I found an another solution with the COM class:

```
$ADSI = new COM("LDAP:");
$user = $ADSI->OpenDSObject("LDAP://servername/userdn, $ldapadmin, $ldappass, 1);
$user->SetPassword($userNewPass);
$user->SetInfo();
```

I hope it can help people :)